# sql server trigger to save all user's actions

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, logging

I want to make a trigger in ms sql server which saves every insert,update or delete had been made in my database and which user made the change.Something like a log file or exactly a log file.
What i've made so far is this:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER Log_Creators_Modifiers ON Quotation
FOR INSERT,UPDATE AS 

  DECLARE
     @ChangeType NVARCHAR
  BEGIN
  /* 'created' for an INSERT, 'Delete' for DELETE, and 'modified' for UPDATE. */
  IF INSERT()
    BEGIN
        SET @ChangeType ='CREATED';
    END

  ELSE IF UPDATE()
    BEGIN
        SET @ChangeType = 'MODIFIED';
    END

  ELSE IF DELETE()
    BEGIN
        SET @ChangeType = 'DELETE';
    END

 END
```

Any help pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not hugely easy but as ever someone has got there beofre you and save you the work

[Audit triggers](http://www.nigelrivett.net/AuditTrailTrigger.html)

does that help at all

or maybe this one where the nice man has even done the script dynamically to add the audit to all the tables

[More triggers](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx)

I wouldn't write this myself - just copy what's already there